# returning inside 'if let' and else

Tags: swift

I have the following function. I understand that I should also provide a return for the case that dateValue is nil. But returning nil isn't allowed by the compiler. What is the twist im my thought?

```
func dateFromIsoString(dateString: String) -> NSDate {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

    let dateValue: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

    if let dateValue = dateValue {
        return dateValue
    }else{
        //return what?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allowed to return `nil` because you're not returning an optional - therefore change the return type to `NSDate?`.

Because, if `dateFromString` fails to parse the string it returns `nil` anyway, you don't need to bother with the `if let` statement. Instead, you could write:

```
return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Comment: ... which can be simplified to `return dateValue` without any if/let :)

Comment: Absolutely, I was just about to write that too :)